# Application execution slow, on some client machines?

Tags: c#, performance, clickonce, antivirus

HI Guys,

We are providing clickonce solutions to generate reports using Aspose.Slides. and the application works fine in all machines except , for our clients in UK, the application execution is  very slow. we thought it might be because of distances to the datacenter, which slows down few downloads, but it even works on lower connectivity than the clients connection.

and the PC which the application run has enough hardware resources too. only thing we found strange is they had trend micro office scan installed with some extra security settings, would that be causing the problem.

we couldn't do any debugging because, the application doesnt fail, but it takes ages to do the same process it does in other machines within 2,3 minutes. it only happens in a particular office on all machines.

any suggestion guys??/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add logging to critical parts of your app, record timestamps and then see what parts of your code take up most of the time.

This will be a reasonably good basis for further investigation.

Alternatively, you can attempt to profile the application on a clients' machine with something like [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Hi i already have a log, and i see which parts are taking more time. the same thing works fine in lower performance/ connectivity PCs faster.

anyway thanks for reminding about dotTrace :D